# Generate date range based on the date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let say i have this table

```
   Date     Inventory Sold
----------  --------------
14/04/2014         9
15/04/2014        21 
16/04/2014        10
17/04/2014        20
18/04/2014        12
19/04/2014        25
20/04/2014        33
```

--and many more dates

how do i make it to a table like this

```
  Date Range     Inventory Sold
--------------  ----------------
   xxx-xxx             50
   xxx-xxx             44
```

the `Date Range` is suppose to be the range by week, eg: `14/04/2014 - 20/04/2014`

Answer (score 1):

Group your data by the date truncated to "whole weeks", like for example:

```
with data as (
   select date '2014-04-14' sold_date, 9 inventory_sold from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-15', 21 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-16', 10 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-17', 20 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-18', 12 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-19', 25 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-20', 33 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-21',  1 from dual
)
select trunc(sold_date,'IW') week_start
     , sum(inventory_sold)
  from data
 group by trunc(sold_date,'IW')
 order by trunc(sold_date,'IW')
```

IW is ISO Week, meaning it uses monday-sunday weeks. Trunc(date,'IW') gives the monday of the week.

If you need to display the range, then you can use something like:

```
with data as (
   select date '2014-04-14' sold_date, 9 inventory_sold from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-15', 21 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-16', 10 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-17', 20 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-18', 12 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-19', 25 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-20', 33 from dual
   union all
   select date '2014-04-21',  1 from dual
)
select to_char(trunc(sold_date,'W'),'DD-MM-YY')
       ||'->'||
       to_char(trunc(sold_date,'W')+6,'DD-MM-YY') week
     , sum(inventory_sold)
  from data
 group by trunc(sold_date,'W')
 order by trunc(sold_date,'W')
```

Hope this is useful :-)

Comment: yes im doing this solution too but i'm a bit lost how to combine the 2 column `start of the week` and `end of the week`. I have this `select trunc(to_date(l_date), 'D') as weekStart,
trunc(to_date(l_date), 'D') + 6 as weekEnd
from table`

Comment: because if i concate it say the 6 number is not valid something

Comment: If you just concatenate your two expressions, there will be implicit conversions that probably is the cause of your number not valid error. Use explicit conversion with to_char like my second example shows, that way you are in control of the date-to-string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Pointing you to:

```
 WHERE
                date >= 'selected_date_low'
                AND date <= '$selected_date_high'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidSegonds Uh Actually i disagree with you on that point. I mmight be wrong but the OP asked for how to select all items inside a time period. I have given him the information to how to select only the appropiate items, what he still has to do is count them.

Where am i wrong with my answer?